# php- error in sql syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, mariadb

I am trying to insert form data into one of the tables in my database. Data to be inserted are name, email, current date and users interests.
Here is the code.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $intrests = $_POST['intrests'];
   $default_intrests = array("mob","pcs","scm","oth");
   $interests = "";
   if (count($intrests) == 0) {
      $interests = implode(",", $default_intrests);
   }
   else {
          $interests = implode(",", $intrests);
   }

   $sqll="insert into subscriptions (name,email,subdate,intrests) values ($name,$email,CURRENT_DATE, $interests)";
   $insert = mysqli_query($link, $sqll);
   if (!$insert) {
      echo mysqli_error($link);
   }
}
```

On form submit, the following error is displayed:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dsa,asdf@qwer.com,CURRENT_DATE, mob)' at line 1

Comment: Add single quote for string value in your query.'

Comment: Use prepared statements an bind variables to stop all sorts of problems, adding quotes is only a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `'` to the value since some of them are `string`

```
 $sqll="insert into subscriptions (name,email,subdate,intrests)
     values ('$name','$email',CURRENT_DATE, '$interests')";
```

In fact,it's a bad idea to write parameter into to your sql directly,you had better to use [prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to do it and avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("insert into table values('data1', 'data2' )");
```

Comment: Can you add more context to your answer? Why should one use the deprecated `mysql_*` methods any longer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // User Entered fields
    // *** This is dangerous, it is subject to sql injection, 
    $query = "insert into subscriptions(name,email,subdate,intrests)
             values ('$name','$email',CURRENT_DATE, '$interests')";

    $result = mysqli_query( $link, $query);

    // *** Error checking, what if !$result? eg query is broken

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if(!$row){

        echo "No Row inserted";
    }
    else {
       echo "OK";
    }
```

If any PHP variable is going to be used, you should never use **mysqli_query()**, but always stick to prepared statements, like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into subscriptions name,email,subdate,intrests)
                             values (?,?,CURRENT_DATE, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $class);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
```

Comment: Your call to `bind_param()` needs the extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing current date into variable

something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $intrests=$_POST['intrests'];
            $CURRENT_DATE = date("Y-m-d");
            $default_intrests=array("mob","pcs","scm","oth");
            $interests="";
            if(count($intrests)==0){
                $interests= implode(",", $default_intrests);
            }else{
                $interests= implode(",", $intrests);
            }

            $sqll="insert into subscriptions (name,email,subdate,intrests) values ('$name','$email','CURRENT_DATE', '$interests')";
            $insert= mysqli_query($link, $sqll);
            if (!$insert) {
                echo mysqli_error($link);
            }
        }
}
```